# How to solve an error object variable or with block variable not set?

Tags: excel, vba

The code is given below.

> Run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set.

It works perfectly sometime but sometime shows the given error.

```
Option Explict 

Public wb As Workbook
Private rowMsg As Integer

Public Sub showMsg(pMsg As String, Optional pColorError As Boolean,
     Optional pColorSuccessful As Boolean)

    With wb.sheets("Setup")
        .Rows(rowMsg).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Rows(rowMsg).VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .Rows(rowMsg).WrapText = True
        .Rows(rowMsg).Orientation = 0
        .Rows(rowMsg).AddIndent = False
        .Rows(rowMsg).IndentLevel = 0
        .Rows(rowMsg).ShrinkToFit = False
        .Rows(rowMsg).ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .Rows(rowMsg).MergeCells = True

        .Cells(rowMsg, 1).Value = Now & Space(3) & pMsg

        If pColorSuccessful Then
            .Cells(rowMsg, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        End If
        If pColorError Then
            .Cells(rowMsg, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End With

    rowMsg = rowMsg + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: a) in which line do you get the error? b) how do you initialize `rowMsg` before you run the macro the first time? Eg add a `If rowMsg = 0 Then rowMsg = 1` as first line in `Sub showMsg` to make sure it is intitialized. And you must declare it as `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle `Private rowMsg As Long`

Comment: The only thing that may cause *this* error is `wb` being `Nothing`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ at (With wb.sheets("Setup")) this line i have error an error.

Comment: @mak then see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54632688/3219613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably that you did not initialize your global variables:

```
Public wb As Workbook
Private rowMsg As Long '<-- needs to be long not integer.
```

If you then run `showMsg` for the first time `wb` is `Nothing` and `rowMsg` is `0` (which is not a valid row number, as it starts with row = 1).

So test if your variables were initialized before you run any code on them.

```
Public Sub showMsg(pMsg As String, Optional pColorError As Boolean, Optional pColorSuccessful As Boolean)

    'test if global variables were initialized, if not do it.
    If wb Is Nothing Then 
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    If rowMsg = 0 Then rowMsg = 1

    'your code here …
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

There are only three objects in the program you list: wb, The worksheet named "Setup" and the cell defined by Rowmsg. In order to get the error in this listing one of these three doesn't exist. Either there is no sheet called "Setup", the workbook object pointed to by wb does not exist or (and this is most like) the variable RowMsg holds an invalid value for the use you are making of it. At a guess you are using Find to set the row number and the error occurs when it doesn't find a result.

When you get the error choose debug and examine the line that is reporting the error. You can then use "View, Call Stack" in the vb editor to step back through your program to see what failed to set the variable correctly

Comment: If there is no sheet called "Setup", there will be "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range". If `RowMsg` holds an invalid value, there will be "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error". There is only one possibility for an error 91 in the given code.